# Is it good to build a gRPC server on an Android device?

Tags: android, service, grpc, grpc-java

gRPC is a good thing, and I found that I can use it on Android, both client and server, so I plan to build a gRPC server in my app for IPC.

The question is that what are the disadvantages of building a gRPC server on Android?

Comment: Are you using C++ or Java?

Comment: @EricAnderson java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gRPC Java does not support any server for Android.

That said I have [tried running Netty on Android](https://github.com/ejona86/grpc-java/tree/toy-with-netty-on-android) and it worked at the time. I'm pretty certain TLS would not work for some Android versions.

Comment: Is there any example how we can run gRPC server on Android, either using java or c++?

Comment: C++ servers are available on Android. See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/android/helloworld