# gRPC server for Android

Tags: android, server, protocol-buffers, grpc, dagger

I'm new to Android. I need to build a gRPC server on the Android platform. I saw that people tried doing that, but did not succeed. It was stated that Netty was not supported on Android. Is there a way to build gRPC/proto (maybe using Dagger) server? Any help/examples will be much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to use the server for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44121743/4690866 is still accurate, except that there is some work going toward [gRPC-on-Binder](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L73-java-binderchannel.md) for cross-process communication.

Comment: What I need to implement is: the server on PC initiates a handshake and sends a request to Android 'client'. Android side needs to perform some tasks on getting a request and respond with a status. It seems that Android needs to serve as a server to the 'server'. I'm not very experienced with server/client programming, I was trying to build an Android side server, with no success. The sides are going to have Ethernet connection, which i also could not get to work with the later Android versions, where Ethernet API is available anymore. :-) Thank you for you help!

Comment: Meant to say Ethernet API is NOT available anymore.                                               I have looked at the example you sent a link to. I think I tried it (I tried so many :-) ) and it did not work. I will try it again. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Update: Since grpc-java 1.49.0 there is an Android-optimized server in grpc-okhttp. See [`OkHttpServerBuilder`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/okhttp/OkHttpServerBuilder.html).

---

There is no HTTP/2 gRPC server available for Android. While the Netty server does run on Android, it is poorly optimized (size, memory, cpu) for Android and is not officially supported by the gRPC team because it doesn't represent their expectations for a server running on Android. I also expect that TLS may not be functional on some Android versions (due to ALPN APIs).

That said, if you need a HTTP/2 gRPC server on Android and don't care about TLS and performance (e.g., for use in tests), then I'd expect grpc-netty to mostly "just work." You may experience an error during compilation about duplicate files in `META-INF/services`, but that can be resolved with `packagingOptions` (ideally "merge", but "pickFirst" probably functions).

Note that C++ servers are supported on Android. There's even [an example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/android/helloworld). This is also a different discussion than in-process servers (which is supported) and [the in-progress Binder-based transport](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L73-java-binderchannel.md).

Comment: Thank you very much @Eric Anderson for more info! I need to consider the options.

Comment: Another question: if it's not gRPC, maybe there is another solution for the Android protobuf-based server?

Comment: I've updated the answer now that gRPC-Java supports an Android server.